Understanding softmax as an activation function, and sparsity in data and gradients
I’m working on a project that includes a probabilistic model that uses one hots, and also occasionally partially freezes weights or zeros gradients to specific regions of the weights. In some parts of the model, we are also trying to use softmax activations to enhance the probabilistic interpretation of those parts of the model. We are trying to have some more interpretability and see if we can also use them to improve our classification later on.
However I’m getting stuck on few of these experiments and I often find the model can easily diverge. From what I saw I believe these are (part of) the problem- the softmax function tends to give too much weight to small inputs, an effect that worsens as you softmax again, also the partial freezing of weight (inside one layer, not the common partial freezing of layers ) or in some cases the gradient itself is already sparse which I think can affect the optimizer. The one-hot inputs are also a thing and probably contribute but I’m not sure I have a different option at the moment. So I have a problematic activation, a sparse input, and a sparse gradient
Are there any literature that research these issues or similar? And have you tried anything and had success with these scenarios?
I’ve tried a few gists on the softmax function or to replace it with something else and add a normalization (to sum to 1) but either they didnt help or were too unstable to work with, now I’m moving on to the data itself and the gradients. We are trying other different things but I’ll like to first see if it’s possible and if not at least understand more/why on these topics.
I appreciate your help.
